# How to navigate between Facebook tabs?

Tags: javascript, facebook-apps

I have created a page in facebook. I have added a couple of tabs to it - 'Welcome' and 'Videos' (both of them are iframe based). I have set 'Welocome' as default tab so that whenever user visits this page he will be presented with the 'welcome' tab. Now in the canvas page of 'welcome' I have a link that says 'Click here to see our videos'. when user clicks on this link I want him to be directly navigated to the 'videos' tab. What script do i need to add in 'welcome' in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in an a href use target="top"

with a javascript redirect use : top.location.href =

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can just use a link, but make sure you copy all of the url, every single bit.

It may be not this simple, but I think it might be.

Could you give us a link to the page. That would help.